# spark.yarn.jars - py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.None. Trace:

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a spark job using a spark2-submit on command. The version of the spark installed on the cluster is cloudera's spark2.1.0 and I am specifying my jars for version 2.4.0 using conf spark.yarn.jars as shown below -

```
spark2-submit \
 --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/virtualenv/path/bin/python \
 --conf spark.yarn.jars=hdfs:///some/path/spark24/*\
 --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1\
 --conf spark.task.cpus=2\
 --executor-cores 2\
 --executor-memory 4g\
 --driver-memory 4g\
 --archives /virtualenv/path \
 --files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml \
 --name my_app\
  test.py
```

This is the code I have in test.py -

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

print("Spark Session created")
```

On running the submit command, I see messages like below -

```
yarn.Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying hdfs:///some/path/spark24/some.jar
```

And then I get this error on the line where spark session is being created -

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 310, in getOrCreate
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 259, in _ensure_initialized
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 117, in launch_gateway
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 175, in java_import
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.1.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.120904/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 323, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.None. Trace:
Authentication error: unexpected command.
```

the py4j in the error is coming from the existing spark and not the versions in my jar. Were my spark24 jars not picked up? The same code runs ok if I remove the conf for jars but probably from the existing spark version 2.1.0. Any clues on how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that python was running from the wrong place. I had to submit from correct place this way -

PYTHONPATH=./${virtualenv}/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ spark2-submit